# jQuery variable and execution delay

Tags: jquery

First of all, sorry for the confusing title. I am running into kind of a silly problem in jQuery. Here's my code:

```
$j('.parent').hover(function(){
     var newWidth = $j(this).find('img').length * 70; // I need number of images within parent and multiply it by 70
     $j(this).stop().animate({'width':newWidth},700); // <-- This does not work
}, function(){
     $j(this).stop().animate({'width':'70'},700); // Back to original width
});
```

But the there's no animation. If I alert the newWidth, it gives me correct answer. I suspect that the animation is executed simultaneously while the value is being assigned to newWidth and hence, nothing happens. Do i need to add delay between assigning variable and executing animation. Is there another efficient way?

UPDATE: The css of the .parent is **inline** and it is following:

```
element.style {
background-color: #000000;
border-color: #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0;
clear: both;
height: 75px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Setting a variable is not asynchronous, so you don't need a delay. What kind of element is it that has class `.parent` and could you provide the css for that class?

Comment: the element with class 'parent' is a DIV. I have added the CSS of the .parent. Do note that CSS is dynamic and it is inline in the DIV itself.

Comment: so that all that css is in a style tag in the div (which makes me cringe, but ok), what about the style for the "parent" class?  As Wouter J has shown, your code does work, so there is obviously something else going on if you can't get it to animate

Comment: I got it working. This particular script was inside a setTimeout function. I increased the timeout and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Which width do you want to change? The `.parent` width or the `.parent img` width? Because you change the width of the `this` element, which is `.parent`. So it won't animate the image.

And your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/WouterJ/QvmBa/

Comment: Yes I want to change width of '.parent'. I have added a few more details to the question.

Comment: I got it working. This particular script was inside a setTimeout function. I increased the timeout and it started working.